# Are these two styles of C function pointer definition different?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I have caught myself accidentally using two different styles of C function pointer definitions in different places and have decided to write a minimal program to test these differences.

The two styles in question are:

```
int (comp (int))
```

and

```
int (*comp)(int)
```

I wrote a minimal program that uses both of these styles for the same function pointer, one for the *declaration* of a function and one for the *definition* of the same function, to see what the compiler would have to say about it.

Declaration:

```
int a_or_b (int (*a_fn)(), int (b_fn()), int (*comp)(int));
```

Definition:

```
int a_or_b (int (a_fn()), int (*b_fn)(), int (comp(int)))
{
    int out = a_fn ();
    if (comp (out))
        out = b_fn ();
    return out;
}
```

As you can (hopefully) see, for the first parameter in the declaration I used the style `int (*a_fn)()`, while in the definition of the function, I used the style `int (a_fn ())`. I do something similar with the next two arguments.

I speculated that these might be incompatible types, that these styles might be the difference between a pass-by-reference and pass-by-value assignment of the variable, but when I compiled this program the compiler silently and happily compiled it. No errors, no warnings, nothing.

As I've seen very many tutorials advocating for the second style, while I personally prefer the first style for aesthetic purposes, I am interested in what the difference is between these two styles and which is recommended.

Full code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a ();
int b ();
int a_or_b (int (*a_fn)(), int (b_fn()), int (*comp)(int));

int a ()
{
    return 1;
}

int b ()
{
    return 2;
}

int comparison (int param)
{
    return param;
}

int a_or_b (int (a_fn()), int (*b_fn)(), int (comp(int)))
{
    int out = a_fn ();
    if (comp (out))
        out = b_fn ();
    return out;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf ("%i\n", a_or_b (a, b, comparison));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In a function parameter list, 'functions' get converted to function pointers.  ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes) says: _¶8 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘function returning type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘pointer to function returning type’’…_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a function parameter list, functions get converted to function pointers.  The C11 standard, ISO/IEC 9899:2011, §6.7.6.3 **Function declarators (including prototypes)** says:

> ¶8 A declaration of a parameter as "function returning type" shall be adjusted to "pointer to function returning type"…

So, as written, the parameters are all treated as 'pointer to function'.  It is best to be self-consistent, though.

Note that a function cannot return a function:

> ¶1 A function declarator shall not specify a return type that is a function type or an array type.

Outside a function declarator (the argument list of a function definition or function declaration), the notations are different:

```
int (*a_fn)();
int (b_fn());
```

The first of these declares (defines) a variable called `a_fn` — a pointer to a function returning `int` with an unspecified (but not variadic) argument list.

The second of these declares the existence of a function called `b_fn` that returns an `int` with an unspecified (but not variadic) argument list (and has a superfluous set of parentheses; it could be written `int b_fn();` and it means the same thing).

Comment: This answer seems to cover every case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Both `int (comp (int))` and `int (*comp)(int)` are equivalent when used as a function parameters. Function designators are converted to pointers to the function itself.

C11-§6.3.2.1:

> A function designator is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator,<sup>65)</sup> or the unary `&` operator, a function designator with type "function returning type" is converted to an expression that has type "pointer to function returning type".

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Are there cases where these two styles behave differently?

Comment: @MarcusHarrison At the top level, `int (comp(int))` is a prototype for a function named `comp` that takes and returns an `int`, while `int (*comp)(int)` is a pointer-to-function.